# Using assertRaises without self in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to test one failure scenario in one of my python file as follows:

**source.py**

```
def myfunc():
     a()
```

associated **test.py**

```
def testMyFuncException():
     a = Mock()
     a.side_effect = MyError
     with self.assertRaises(MyError) as _ : <--- THIS LINE I CANNOT USE self.assertRaises
       ..
```

But here I cannot use self as it's not associated with any class. So I am not getting any clue regarding how to do this.

**EDIT**

I have done it as follows now as per suggestions:

```
def testMyFuncException(TestCase):
     a = Mock()
     a.side_effect = MyError
     with TestCase.assertRaises(MyError) as _ :
     ...
```

Now I am getting error as follows:

```
E       fixture 'TestCase' not found
```

Comment: You will need to pass the responsible `TestCase` into `testMyFuncException`.  Or use a different unit test framework.

Comment: In your update, you need to pass an instance of the `TestCase` class.

Comment: Are you mixing `unittest` and `pytest`? (If so, don't.) Perhaps you need https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another possibility is to use [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) instead of unittest. In this case you don't need a separate test class:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_myfunc_exception():
    a = Mock()
    a.side_effect = MyError
    with pytest.raises(MyError, match="my exception message"):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `TestCase` fixture in the `unittest` testing framework. The normal way to do this is to create a class inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`. You will then be able to use the `self.assertRaises` method, along with the other asserts in the `TestCase` class:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock

class TestMyFunc(TestCase):
    def test_myfunc_exception(self):
        a = Mock()
        a.side_effect = MyError
        with self.assertRaises(MyError) as _ :
        ...
```